# Prove that $M$ is $0$ dimensional manifold if and only if it is countable and discrete

Tags: calculus, manifolds

Prove that $M$ is $0$-dimensional manifold if and only if it is countable and discrete$$--$$
I understood how to prove, using the diffeomorphism characteristic of manifold, that $M$ is discrete, but didn't know how to continue to show it means it's countable.
In the other direction, I didn't succeed to build $C^1$ diffeomorphism which is locally $M$ and would like help in that.
Thanks!

Comment: A manifold is supposed to be a [second-countable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-countable_space) space.

Answer (score 0):

To prove that is $0$-dimensional is equivalent to prove that there exists a diffeomorphism $\phi: A\subseteq  \mathbb{N}\to M$.

$M$ is countable, so that there exists a bijective map $\phi: A\subseteq \mathbb{N}\to M$.

The map $\phi$ is continuos if and only if the inverse image of a singleton is open, because $M$ is discrete. But $\phi$ is bijective, so the inverse image of a point is a point too, that is open in the discrete topology of $A\subseteq \mathbb{N}$. The map is also open because the image of a point is a point, that is open on $M$. Thus $\phi$ is an homeomorphism.

The map is clearly also a diffeomorphism and the $\psi_\beta\circ \phi\circ \psi_\alpha^{-1}\colon \{0\} \to \{0\} $ is of course a smooth map.

Use the hint in the comment to prove the converse one :)